# Is there a way using jQuery to stagger PHP queries in a page?

Tags: php, jquery, lazy-loading

There is a page with several php queries being called... each php query pulls data from the db to create an analytics graph.  Initially, was thinking about using the jQuery lazy loader plugin... however, do not believe it will work in this context.

What I want to do is when a user is looking at the first graph (before scrolling down), that it will make an AJAX call and run the php Query, show a loading gif, and then finally display the graphics/graph for the outputted query... as the user continues to scroll down, more queries will be called.  The issue now is that the page calls all the queries at once and it takes a while to load.

Any thoughts on how to do this using javascript, jQuery, or any other lazy loading technique?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jPjPM/1/ display a div every X seconds, this one is set to 3.

Comment: UPDATE:  The images are actually going to be interactive graphs... so I guess you can imagine a div (class='graph') that inside it will call another php file to do the query and return the interactive graph.  I'll likely have to use the jQuery load function and a plugin like jQuery Waypoints as mentioned.

Another stipulation would be that only one graph query(ies) is called at a time.  Once the first graph is displayed (result returned), then if the next graph div is in the screen area (jQuery Waypoints magic), it will be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: That looks promising... I know the jQuery Lazy Loader plugin was last updated late 2007 and isn't functional with the latest versions of jQuery.

I will test the jQuery Waypoints plugin today.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno how you can generate different graph within only one page.

Anyway you need to do something like this:

```
<img src="graph1.php">
[page]
<img src="graph2.php">
<img src="graph3.php">
[ more more page ]
<img src="graph4.php">
```

In this way you have differnet page that will build up differnet graph as the user scrolls down. And you can use lazy loading here.

Comment: It's actually not a image, at first I thought it was... rather, its an interactive graph.  But, similarly, each img would be represented by a div (class="graph") that would display a loading gif until the php file called within this div returns a result.  I'll likely have to use the jQuery Waypoints plugin and the jQuery load function.